# Subjunctive usage and if only with

Tags: grammar, usage

Is ***Were he*** in the last sentence the same as ***If it were***, which I learned is a subjective form? But the following ***may have felt*** is not a subjunctive, which makes the sentence obscure to me. Is the sentence grammatical, isn't it? If so, can I use ***might have felt***, which is a subjunctive form? What is the difference in meaning between the two verb phrases?

And is ***if only with*** the contraction of ***if only he could attack with***? I've searched the phrase, but I am not sure what that means.

> Reflection and reflecting are a psychologist’s favorite words, and
> with good reason: a reflective person has access to his inner motives,
> feelings, and thoughts, and is able to see the (psycho)logical
> connection between them and his actions. Because he’s keeping an eye
> on his dark side, he’s better able to keep it in check. For instance,
> he’ll recognize that the aversion he feels toward his coworker isn’t
> actually because she’s supposedly unfriendly — it’s because of the
> envy he feels at her success. By seeing this in himself, he will
> likely conclude that it really wouldn’t be fair to target this person.
> Chances are good he’ll behave amicably toward her and manage to
> regulate his green-eyed monster internally. Because he has access to
> his feelings of envy and inferiority, he also has the ability to sway
> these feelings in a more positive direction. ***Were*** he unable to
> admit that his coworker’s success rubbed his ego the wrong way, he
> ***may have felt*** tempted to attack her, ***if only with*** a few verbal jabs to cut her down — even in front of others.

[The Child In You: The Breakthrough Method for Bringing Out Your Authentic Self](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=v-HdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&lpg=PT19&dq=Were%20he%20unable%20to%20admit%20that%20his%20coworker%E2%80%99s%20success%20rubbed%20his%20ego%20the%20wrong%20way,%20he%20may%20have%20felt%20tempted%20to%20attack%20her,%20if%20only%20with%20a%20few%20verbal%20jabs%20to%20cut%20her%20down%20%E2%80%94%20even%20in%20front%20of%20others.&source=bl&ots=USDakNhU8d&sig=ACfU3U2QZLMo9Vo0cjkionmt2FyMOBLd8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj185_QoJD2AhVVyosBHew_DCEQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Were%20he%20unable%20to%20admit%20that%20his%20coworker%E2%80%99s%20success%20rubbed%20his%20ego%20the%20wrong%20way%2C%20he%20may%20have%20felt%20tempted%20to%20attack%20her%2C%20if%20only%20with%20a%20few%20verbal%20jabs%20to%20cut%20her%20down%20%E2%80%94%20even%20in%20front%20of%20others.&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

> ***Were he** unable to admit that his coworker’s success rubbed his ego the*
> *wrong way, he **may have felt** tempted to attack her, **if only** with a few*
> *verbal jabs to cut her down ...*

"Were he" is the equivalent of the conditional phrase "if he were" . The expression "he may have felt tempted to attack her ..." is the other part of the conditional; it expresses the result of the condition being fulfilled.

"Might have felt" is not a subjunctive, but simply the past tense equivalent of "may have felt". Both forms are possible for many speakers and have the same meaning. The "if only" expression is an implicit conditional construction where the focus of "only" is an adjunct.